# Can not find path to host volume in docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

I am working on an application in spring boot in which photos will be uploaded to the server and then read from the server using the url. The application is on the docker and tomcat server. From what I have learned the best way would be to store photos on docker volume using the host. So using the docker-compose.yml file I create the volume and give the path to the host. File fragment:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-app:
    image: app
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,api-docs
      .
      .
      .
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    networks:
      default: 
        ipv4_address: 172.19.0.2
    volumes:
       - ./var/home/my-app:/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app  //"path to the host:path to the docker container"
```

From what I read on the Docker website [there](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/?fbclid=IwAR0NwHUc2W_Ce8T7g_UQC9FL-cmVywgaQksCs_yxFbB4tQQFHxrwVs5mn7Q#short-syntax-3), this is how you should create a path to the host where the photos will be stored, i.e. on the left the path to the host, and on the right the path to the container. The problem is that no path is created or is, but I can't find it. I also have a method that runs every time it checks to see if a path exists:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (!Files.exists(Paths.get("./var/home/my-app"))) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Error initializing directory: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
}
```

And this throws that path does not exists.

So, I have questions:

- Am I creating a good path to the host?
- Or should the path to the host be different?
- If host will be with read write permissions should I add something in docker-compose.yml file?

**Edit**

So to specify my problem. I wanto save files in volume host and then gets image by URL e.g.  localhost:8080/image/12/picture.png
I have to specify path where the files are ulpoded. Method init() checks if path exists and then a path is assigned to the variable root where the files should be saved.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (isProd) {
        root = Paths.get("./var/home/my-app");
    } else {
        root = Paths.get("./uploads");
    }

    if (!Files.exists(root)) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Error initializing directory: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And then I saved files like this:

```
Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);  //filePath: ./upluads/image/12/picture.png
```

filePath should contains path to host and unique folders for each photo with id in the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your check-method is inside your Spring application, i.e., inside the my-app container, you need to check for the

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app
```

folder, instead of the

```
./var/home/my-app
```

folder:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  if (!Files.exists(Paths.get("/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app"))) {
    try {
        Files.createDirectory(root);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Error initializing directory: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

On the first use of the volume-folder, the respective folder on the host should be created (as you are using the short-notation for the volume definition).
The folder that should be created would be alongside your docker-compose.yml file, named var/home/my-app

To be able to create subfolders based on the provided url, for instance `localhost:8080/image/12/picture.png`, you need to define the endpoint `/image/{id}/{image_name}` where the `id` is a path variable and `image_name` is a path variable.

Similarly, your POST request that you use to upload the file needs to have `id` path variable, which you translate to a folder name in your code, and create it if it is not present.

Regarding your third question:

> If host will be with read write permissions should I add something in docker-compose.yml file?

That depends on whether you defined a user to isolate your container.
Have a look here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/
Unless you did something like this, your process inside the container is running as root and can then write on your host regardless of missing permissions.

Edit to clarify the folders that are created due to the line in  docker-compose.yml:

```
 - ./var/home/my-app:/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app  //"path to the host:path to the docker container"
```

As you correctly commented on this line,
the ./var/home/my-app is the path on your host machine.
Since it starts with a '.' it is a relative path and will start at the current location where the docker-compose.yml file is located.

The second part: /var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app is the path inside the container, which gets mapped to the folder on your host.
This is an absolute path, since it starts with '/'.

Anything that your application places in this folder (/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app) will be accessible on your host machine (so outside of your docker container) in the other folder (./var/home/my-app).
They are the same space on your hard drive, once accessed from inside the container and once accessed from the host.

In you application that runs in the docker-container, you exclusively use the path: /var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app.

Outside of the container, so on your host, you exclusively use the path ./var/home/my-app.

Suppose on your host the docker-compose.yml file is located in the folder:

```
/home/thortiede/docker/docker-compose.yml
```

Then you will find the contents of the shared folder under

```
/home/thortiede/docker/var/home/my-app
```

If you want to have files from your host accessible inside the docker-container, you need to put them in this directory.
Then, from inside the docker-container, you access these files by navigating to :

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app
```

Comment: So if I put this path /var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app how do I check where is host placed? Because if I want to save files inside host I should gave path to the host or am I wrong?

Comment: I tried to explain the folder structure a bit more in detail. If that does not address your question, please elaborate more.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer because it explained a lot to me.  To indicate the place to save the files I have to specify path: `/home/thortiede/docker/var/home/my-app` or `/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app` ?

Comment: When you want to check the path in your application that runs in the container, you need to use the `/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app` path.

Comment: But what if I need to specify path where the uploded files will be saved?

Comment: The way things are set up, you specify the path when you create the volume in your docker-compose.yml file. Please provide an example for what you mean exactly by "need to specify". Where do you need to specify it (in your Java application, when creating the docker-container, or somewhere else) and at which timepoints (when your ``init()`` method is called, or when the container is created?)

Comment: I edited question. So I want to save picture in volume host directory and then have to display picture by using URL path e.g. localhost:8080/image/12/picture.png

Comment: If you want to be able to do to a GET request of the form `localhost:8080/image/12/picture.png`, then you need to define the endpoint `/image/{id}/{image_name}` where the `id` is a path variable and `image_name` is a path variable. Similarily, your POST request that you use to upload the file needs to have `id` path variable, which you translate to a folder name in your code, and create it if it is not present. Does that help you? If so, I can add it to my answer. If not, I am not sure what exactly you want to accomplish,  I am sorry. (english is not my first language)

Answer (score 1):

You're currently mounting the folder `/var/home/my-app` from your host machine to the folder `/var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app` inside the container.

As your application is running inside a container the method you've written

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (!Files.exists(Paths.get("./var/home/my-app"))) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Error initializing directory: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
}
```

creates the directory structure `/var/home/my-app` **inside the container filesystem.**

If your Java code is written to save data under the folder `/var/home/my-app` you should create your volume in the following way:

```
volumes:
   - /var/home/my-app:/var/home/my-app
```

Comment: "creates the directory structure /var/home/my-app inside the container filesystem." if I understand correctly, the path to the host will be as follows: /var/lib/docker/containers/docker_my-app/var/home/my-app? I am newbie at docker so sorry for this question if this is stupid question :|

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. Let's verify two things.

1. Where do you want to save the files on your host machine ?
2. In your Spring project, how does your code save the uploaded pictures ?

Comment: 1. I think it will be good to save files in the same place where is located project or create own place in host machine. 
2. The app saves photos in Base64 and next it places the photos in the indicated path e.g. if I run my project locally I have folder inside my project ./uploads and next  is created new folder with the name ID and that's where the photos are kept like this ./uploads/123/photo.jpg. And I want to store files the same in host e.g. I have base directory and next is created folder with ID and put there photo.

Comment: Could you please then share your Dockerfile + the code that saves the photos in the`./uploads` folder ?

Comment: Hmm I just only want to know what is a path to host e.g. if I gave the path as above, where exactly is the host in host machine?